# LinearLayout horizontally align textview to center of button inside linearlayout vertical orientation

Tags: android, android-layout, alignment, android-linearlayout, android-framelayout

I have a LinearLayout with vertical orientation.
It has two children elements - a TextView and a Button.
The button is to be aligned to the right/end of parent.
and the textView must be aligned such that center of both siblings match.

Constraints:
Due to some reasons, use of RelativeLayout is NOT allowed.
Use of ConstraintLayout is allowed. I think it might help.
(Although i want to avoid increasing complexity as much as I can.)

Can this be achieved?
If yes, How can this be achieved?

Here is my activity_main.xml layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         android:id="@+id/frame_layout_container"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         tools:context=".MainActivity"
         tools:layout_height="400dp">

<View android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="400dp"
      android:background="@color/green">
</View>

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start|bottom"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/left_overlay"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start|bottom"
            android:layout_weight="0.65"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:text="John Mayer Doe"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                tools:text="Title"/>

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewSubTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:minLines="1"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:text="Alice Bob Charlie Dave Eve Frank"
                tools:text="Subtitle"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/right_overlay"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
            android:layout_weight="0.35"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|end"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textontopofbutton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:text="text on top"
                tools:text="on top of button"/>

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/bottomrightbutton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                android:text="Click me now"
                tools:text="Tap here now"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

colors.xml for ref:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<color name="colorPrimary">#008577</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#00574B</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#D81B60</color>
<color name="colorAccentBright">#D81B60</color>
<color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
<color name="black">#000000</color>
<color name="green">#3D9D2A</color>
<color name="red">#D80D15</color>
<color name="yellow">#B7AB4C</color>
<color name="maroon">#BB4767</color>
</resources>
```

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.flames

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

Screenshot:
[image: no bounds]
With Layout Bounds:
[image: with bounds]

Goal:
I want the "text on top" to be center-aligned with the button.

I appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: You can do it definitely with constraint layout. Did you try to change it to `ConstraintLayout` yourself?

Comment: Try changing `bottomrightbutton` width to `match_parent`

Comment: @BachVu i do NOT want the button to take up the entire width of the right sidebar, so that's not acceptable. the button must use wrap_content, the question is about alignment of textview with respect to buttonview's center, independent of buttonview's size.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can easily do with `ConstraintLayout` with minimum complexity,

Here is the solution that you can try,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:background="@color/green"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:text="John Mayer Doe"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textViewSubTitle"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/view5" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewSubTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:minLines="1"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Alice Bob Charlie Dave Eve Frank"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/view5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/view5" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textontopofbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="text on top"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomrightbutton"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/bottomrightbutton"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/bottomrightbutton" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bottomrightbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="Click me now"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/view5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/view5" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: i added both of these to gradle dependencies, implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3' and
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3', but the app crashes. I also added multidex, and multidexenabled true, is there something i am missing?

Comment: Please add only Single dependency, either used androidx or support library.

Comment: okay, i added just one "implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'", then the UI had wrong position of text on top, screenshot at https://imgur.com/lVOKBCR

Comment: i am using implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0-beta2' with the above code there is no issue find as you mention. can you please check again

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do either

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/right_overlay"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textontopofbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:text="text on top"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bottomrightbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="Click me now"
        tools:text="Tap here now"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

or using constraint layout

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textontopofbutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
    android:text="text on top"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomrightbutton"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bottomrightbutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:text="Click me now"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textontopofbutton"
    tools:text="Tap here now" />
```

Comment: the solution using linearlayout does not work as expected, the one using constraintlayout worked fine, thanks

Comment: Glad I could Help

Answer (score 0):

I have made a very minor fix to your XML, this should work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/frame_layout_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:layout_height="400dp">

    <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:background="@color/green">
    </View>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start|bottom"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/left_overlay"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start|bottom"
            android:layout_weight="0.65"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:text="John Mayer Doe"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                tools:text="Title"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewSubTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:minLines="1"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:text="Alice Bob Charlie Dave Eve Frank"
                tools:text="Subtitle"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/right_overlay"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
            android:layout_weight="0.35"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|end"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textontopofbutton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:text="text on top"
                tools:text="on top of button"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bottomrightbutton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                android:text="Click me now"
                tools:text="Tap here now"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

All the best :)